# How to pass values from a checkbox array to 3 inputs, without overwriting

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pass values of a checkbox array to 3 inputs, if I check in a value that sends to the first input, then the second checkbox to the second input and then the third checkbox to the third input, then if I choose another value of the checkbox that does not overwrite without first uncheck the checked checkbox value

It could be put an addeventlistener

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="demoForm" id="demoForm">    
    <fieldset>

        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sports[]" value="cycling" /> cycling</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sports[]" value="running" /> running</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sports[]" value="visit gym" /> visit gym</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sports[]" value="swimming" /> swimming</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sports[]" value="team sports" /> team sport(s)</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sports[]" value="other" /> other</label>

    </fieldset>   
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var sports = document.forms['demoForm'].elements[ 'sports[]' ];

for (var i=0, len=sports.length; i<len; i++) {
    sports[i].onclick = doSomething;
}
function doSomething() {
  y=document.getElementById("chk1");
  var sports = document.forms['demoForm'].elements[ 'sports[]' ];

    if ( this.checked) {
        y.value=this.value;

    } else {
        y.value="";
    }
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="chk1" id="chk1"> 
          <input type="text" name="chk2" id="chk2"> 
          <input type="text" name="chk3" id="chk3">
```

I hope to see the solution.

Comment: `then if I choose another value of the checkbox that does not overwrite without first uncheck the checked checkbox value` this line is not clear enough

Comment: What I want to say is how I can choose and show 6 values of the checkbox to 3 inputs without problems, each time you click that the value appears, and if the input is not empty that moves to the other input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a set of conditional code which will work for you as i understood your question, and it's explained with comments along the way.

```
   var sports = document.forms['demoForm'].elements[ 'sports[]' ];

   for (var i=0, len=sports.length; i<len; i++) {
   sports[i].onclick = doSomething;
   } 

function doSomething() {
       x = document.getElementById("chk1");
       y = document.getElementById("chk2");
       z = document.getElementById("chk3");

    /*if a checkbox is checked and the first input is empty, then put the checkbox 
      value in the first input */

     if ( this.checked && x.value =="") {
          x.value = this.value;

    /*now if the first input is filled already, check if the second is empty and put 
      the checkbox value into the second*/

     } else if (this.checked &&  y.value =="") {
                y.value = this.value ;

      /*now if the second input is filled already, check if the third is empty and 
        put the checkbox value into the third*/

     } else if (this.checked && z.value ==""){
                 z.value = this.value ;

     /* if a checkbox is checked and all 3 inputs are filled already so it gets to 
     this condition, then alert the user and make the checkbox shouldn't be checked*/

     }else if (this.checked) {
              alert("First un-check another box to check this box");
              this.checked = false;

     /* if the user unchecked a checkbox, then check in which input the value of this 
        checkbox was displayed and empty this input */

     } else if (!this.checked){
             switch(this.value){
             case y.value:
             y.value="";
             break;
             case x.value:
             x.value="";
             break;
             case z.value:
             z.value="";
              } 
     }
}
```

Comment: I did not comment at the time but it really worked, thanks man!, God Bless you.